# Правописание: "с" или "со"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: *киста **с** взвесью внутри* или *киста **со** взвесью внутри?* Да, понимаю, что три согласные, но в правиле стоит, что если слово начинается на "с" или на "з", тогда "со", а здесь начинается на "в".

Answer (score 1):

В правиле так, но... Если посмотреть подобные сочетания в книжках (в качестве слова с предлогом может быть "*взвод*", "*взвешенный*", *взвинченный*"...) то можно увидеть, что в издательской практике либо буквально следуют правилу (не упомянуто такое сочетание - не будем добавлять -о), либо следуют простой логике: вставка перед "означенным в правилах" сочетанием букв дополнительной согласной **в-** вместо **-о** произношения не упрощает (четыре согласных подряд при *-з-* на месте), и из фонетических соображений *-о* полезно добавить. Излишне буквальная трактовка правил порой приводит и к пяти согласным (из газеты МК): "*с взгромоздившейся* на сцену толпой". Можно "изловчиться" с произношением, но результат будет невольной данью языку суахили, где отдельные согласные могут образовывать даже ударный слог.

Comment: Так как писать правильно ? Киста с взвесью ?

Comment: Я бы написал "со взвесью", хотя документально "правильность" этого недоказуема. Пример из монографии "Геохимия органического вещества в океане", Романкевич, Наука,1977: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=S7gKAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA205&img=1&pgis=1&dq=%D1%81%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8E&sig=ACfU3U1kM_BjLhU27Sf44SsQJc9mGET9fA&edge=0 Таких книжных примеров - множество.

Comment: Ответ понравился, только насчёт суахили странно. Не видно там что-то и трёх подряд согласных, не говоря уже о четырёх — пяти: https://forvo.com/languages-pronunciations/sw/.

Comment: Балдею, кстати, уже полтора года от кенийского гимна. :)

Comment: Там бывают слоги _без_ гласных, которые могут попасть и под ударение (обычно ударный предпоследний слог), напр. слог m в слове mtu (человек). При нарочитом отделении согласных в русском произношении (напр. предлога "с") получается что-то похожее.

Comment: Интересно! Действительно, есть такое, понял, о чём вы. ;) Даже не полтора года, а 2,5: с весны 2017-го заслушивался.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что пишет [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%20(%D1%81%D0%BE)).

Предлог **со** фонетически закономерен перед словами, начинающимися с сочетаний [с, з, ш, ж + согласная] или с согласной [щ]: со ста, со славой, со звездой, со шкафа, со жгутом, со щами.

Также предлог **со** употребляется перед формами с начальными сочетаниями [л, ль, р, м + согласная]: со лба, со мной, со льдом, со ртом; также перед сочетаниями [**в + согласная**]: ***со вт***орника, **со вс**еми, **со вт**орого.

*Он **со взбр**ыкиванием выскочил с крыльца городничего и так проворно побежал, что будочник, стоявший на часах у дома городничего, даже сплюнул...* (М. Булгаков. Необычайное происшествие); *Когда она «устроила» в парламенте небольшую речь правого депутата... Роллинг в первый раз  по-мужски,  дружески, **со встр**яхиванием пожал ей руку* (А. Толстой. Гиперболоид инженера Гарина); сказать **со взд**охом; в связи **со встр**ечей; предложение **со вст**авкой; **со взв**одом солдат; **со взд**орным характером.

Думаю, что правильно надо писать "**со** взвесью внутри".

*Сверху на кольцо накладывается покровное стекло с предварительно нанесенной каплей сусла **со взвесью** спор* (Б. П. Токин. Фитонциды); *Реакция **со взвесью** иодида меди (1) основана на том, что при взаимодействии ионов ртути...* (В. Ф. Крамаренко. Токсикологическая химия)

P. S. Вообще-то согласных — три.

**Дополнение** (после комментария)

1. Мой постскриптум относится только к тому, что в вопросе написано «Да, понимаю, что две согласные» (а на самом деле их три).
2. Если правило рекомендует использовать предлог "со" перед **ст** (со стаканом, со стадом) и **вс** (со вселенной, со всяким), то нам уже **все равно, какая** буква следует потом — гласная или согласная.

Сравните: со **стр**ахом, со **стр**азами, со **стр**емянки, со **ств**орками, со **скл**ада, со **скл**янкой — ни о каких трех согласных и речи нет в правиле (достаточно первых двух), а мы исправно пишем предлог "со".

Точно такие же рассуждения применимы и к начальной конструкции [в + согласная + "дополнительные" согласные]: со **взд**утием, со **взл**омом, со **взм**ахом, со **взгл**ядом, со **взв**изгом, со **всхр**апом, со **вспл**еском.

*Можно поздравить **со встрепкой**, или туча пролетела мимо?* (В. Ян)

Comment: Вот и я ни в одном источнике (включая Розенталя) не встретил упоминания "перед _тремя_ согласными" :). Везде приводят лишь пункт "устойчивые сочетания" (там где "со всеми" и т. п.)

Comment: Ошиблась, потому что копировала текст ,а потом быстро печатала . Понятно ,что там три согласные это и дураку ясно. Вопрос просто был в том,как написать вот и всё. Просто диктуют когда предложения говорят "с"  и поэтому возник вопрос ,как же правильно. В интернете пишут,что это вспомогательно и можно и так и так

Comment: Мне кажется, что я ответила на Ваш вопрос — и рекомендациями, и примерами.